# jQuery - How to revert css changes when using slideToggle()?

Tags: jquery, css

How does one revert the CSS changes when clicking the button a second time to close the expanded div?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#sec_add").hide();
$("#second_address").show();

$('#second_address').click(function(){
    $("#sec_add").slideToggle();
    $('.vertical').css('height','2106px');
    $('#content_main').css('height','2249px');
});

});
```

Or maybe do something with toggleClass()?

```
$( "#second_address" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "second_vertical_line" );
});
```

Comment: It would be clearer if you posted the corresponding HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably toggle an additional class rather than directly changing styles:

```
.vertical {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
.vertical.other {
    height: 40px;
}
#content_main {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#content_main.other {
    height: 40px
}

$('#second_address').click(function () {
    $("#sec_add").slideToggle();
    $('.vertical, #content_main').toggleClass('other');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/L2Zb9/3

Comment: It's literally extending a vertical dividing line and adding space to the bottom of the page to make room for the expanded div.  I kind of feel like it would be a hack to make it work.

Comment: Don't let your feelings get in the way of true greatness.

Comment: lol.  So you are saying I should use it to add a second vertical line and extend the "content_main" without modifying the original values?

Comment: Something like this:

    So it would be something like    $( "#second_address" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "second_vertical_line" );
    });

Comment: God, i have no idea how to break a line on these comments.  I'll update the OP.

Comment: Lemme throw it onto the page.  I'll come back and choose your answer shortly.  No idea why I am getting downvoted..

Comment: Because you haven't provided enough code for us to visualize your issue. You were asked to post HTML.

Comment: This worked perfect.  Thanks.  And fwiw, you seemed to have no issue visualizing it without the html, which was deeply embeded for a simple question.